# how can use Mapbox in unity for windows

Tags: windows, unity-game-engine, mapbox

I have a problem. I want to know how to use Mapbox in unity for windows. Here is a [relevant link](https://github.com/tmpsantos/mapbox-gl-native/tree/tmpsantos-unity_plugin/platform/unity) I found, but I could not understand it.

Is it possible that Mapbox only works for linux?

Answer (score 0):

Yep, that example is only designed to work on OSX & Linux, for now. It's a native extension built on top of Mapbox GL Native, so we'd need to support a number of C++ libraries on Windows, as well as VS-based build system, in order to get it running.

That said, we're hard at work on an improved way of including Mapbox in Unity that will give better flexibility and more importantly look a lot cooler!